# Please can someone explain the notation of this multivariate Taylor expansion?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, taylor-series

Kamanzi-wa-Binyavanga, 2009, wrote the following paper, Calculating Cumulants of a Taylor
Expansion of a Multivariate Function:

[image]

What I am confused about, is how precise the notation. I understand that we take each partial derivative with respect to some point ($r,s,t$ here) between $1$ and $p$, which might be the number of regressors in a statistical setting. What I don't understand is:

1. Why we must sum over each $r,s,t$ individually?
2. Why he sums over $z$ and $s$, not $r$ and $s$ in the double summation
3. Why he actually says each of these summations is from 1 to $p_i$. Am I correct in saying, the third for example, should look like $\frac{1}{3!}\sum_{r=1}^{p_i}\sum_{s=1}^{p_i}\sum_{t=1}^{p_i}$.
4. Lastly, this might seem simple, but if I wanted the Taylor expansion for the whole function $Y$, would I simply add $\sum_{i=1}^{q}$ before the term $c$?

Any help/clarity would be gratefully received. I'm trying to learn to use Einstein notation in this setting, but I need to understand exactly this expansion first.

Answer (score 2):

1. Because this is how Taylor expansion for a function of several variables looks like. For an overview you may consult respective [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor%27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) or any of the numerous lecture notes available online. It is common to use more concise multi-index notation or express summations via vector/matrix products, latter perhaps being more relevant if you are studying Einstein notation
2. It looks like a typo, since $z$ doesn't appear anywhere within that term
3. That's correct. $p_i$ is just the number of arguments (independent variables) of the function $f_i$
4. The whole variable $Y$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{q}$ and each of its elements is explicitly defined as a function of certain $p_i$ variables (notation in the paper allows for them even to constitute nonoverlapping sets). If I understand correctly, in this setting you would compute expansion separately for each element (function). Aggregating them further doesn't make sense, in general